# Change radio button color on click with multiple colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to create Yes/No buttons which have a default state of null, and when pressed, yes goes green, and no goes red.

Here is an example of the code:

```
<label class="formheading">Apparatus group is correct</label>
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="false" class="right">
    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2y" value="Yes">
    <label for="q2y">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2n" value="No">
    <label for="q2n">No</label>
</fieldset>
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ambvdznb/) - as you can see I've only managed to change the button to green for all buttons... but what I'd like is for No to become red once pressed.

I've found some similar solutions, however none seem to work with JQM 1.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add class `.no` to "No" label:

```
<label for="q2n" class="no">No</label>
```

and add this rule:

```
.myform .ui-btn-active.no {
    background-color: red !important;
    border-color: crimson !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
}
```

This would allow you to have more buttons in future if you need.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambvdznb/6/

Answer (score 2):

If you don't plan on adding any other buttons other than two, this worked great for me..

```
.myform .ui-btn-active.ui-last-child{
    background-color: red !important;
    border-color: red !important;
}
```

This selects the last `.ui-btn-active` inside of each `.myform` element. You also don't have to add any extra mark up or classes to your HTML! :)

JFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ambvdznb/2/

Comment: This worked great. The only reason this isn't the accepted answer is because I like the flexibility of adding more buttons should I need them

Answer (score 1):

Just add additional selector for No.

```
.myform .ui-btn-active[for="q2n"] {
    background-color: red !important;
    border-color: red !important;
}
```

See here http://jsfiddle.net/ambvdznb/

Comment: @Frogmouth I think you are incorrect! You need to give a reason

Comment: You're right ... I had some doubts on the selector [attr=value] (cross-browser) but, it's OK (IE7+). My bad. Right now i can't remove my downvote. I can, if u edit some in your answer. :)

Comment: @Frogmouth I make changes :)

Comment: ... I removed my down-vote. My bad. ;) and get UP one.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the labels for the inputs classes like 'yesbutton' and 'nobutton' and then use a simple css-selector to give them different colors like this:

//html

```
<div class="myform">
    <label class="formheading">Question 2</label>

    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="false" class="right">
        <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2y" value="Yes">
        <label for="q2y" class="yesbutton">Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2n" value="No">
        <label for="q2n" class="nobutton">No</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

//css

```
.right {
     float: right !important;
}
.myform {
    padding:20px;
}
.myform .ui-btn-active.yesbutton {
    background-color: green !important;
    border-color: #1F802E !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
}
.myform .ui-btn-active.nobutton {
    background-color: red !important;
    border-color: #1F802E !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The background-color property should be applied to the <label> instead of <input>.

First declare two ids for your  elements:

```
...
<label for="q2y" id="q2yl">Yes</label>
...
<label for="q2n" id="q2nl">No</label>
```

And then extend your CSS for the new elements:

```
.myform #q2yl.ui-btn-active {
    background-color: green !important;
}
.myform #q2nl.ui-btn-active {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

You can remove the existing background-color from your previous element.

```
.myform .ui-btn-active {
    border-color: #1F802E !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ambvdznb/15/)

check it other working answer.. :D

```
.myform .ui-first-child.ui-btn-active {
background-color: green !important;
border-color: #1F802E !important;
color: #fff !important;
text-shadow: none !important;
}
.myform .ui-last-child.ui-btn-active {
background-color: red !important;
border-color: red !important;
color: #fff !important;
text-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to add that css rule:

```
.myform .ui-btn-active[for=q2n] {
background-color: red !important;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ambvdznb/5/)

Comment: @Frogmouth author didn't asked for **best way** of doing that and best way term is subjective. In fact that answer does what **falter** wanted to achieve. So what is your problem? Why you are downvoting correct answer?

Comment: ... however is the same answer that @Probil.

Comment: q2n is a variable, so this answer does not work for me (I perhaps should have specified that in my Q)

Comment: @Frogmouth sooo what? Let me explain you one thing. SO doesn't restrict viewing and answering same question by multiple users simultaneously. So it is possible to get into situation when several users can give similar answer to a question. And my answer is not the same - see link to jsfiddle.

Comment: @falter you had to specify that. Still can't see a reason for downvoting my answer. You asked a question, I provided an answer which is correct answer to your question. Just next time nobody will answer your questions..